# terminate the threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
if(thread.isalive())
{ // Terminate it such that  no CPu memory and resources should be used
}
```

I want to terminate the threads so that no computers resources and memory would be used.Please Guide me in this

Comment: You can interrupt the thread. And in the thread you can check for interrupted status and then *return*

Answer (score 1):

In Java threads will terminate itself after the code in it finished. You don't need to do this manually. If you want to terminate a running thread just call interrupt and the thread will terminate.

Comment: Assuming of course the thread is nice enough to listen to interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't find a live thread after you started it unless:

A) It is still running

B) It is taking a while for the teardown procedure

Therefore, don't. If a thread still runs, it runs for a good reason. If you need task cancellation, there are better ways, such as interruption, boolean check within the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Thread.stop() method will terminate the thread but it is deprecated:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

To terminate a thread, it have to reach the return statement in his *run* method. You can handle the return by checking a variable and set it as you need.